# Can Doctrine save fields which are reserved keys?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a table with "`from`", "`with`" columns too. When I want to persist it, I get an exception:

PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, with, fb_email, fb_id, fb_login_code, fb_hometown, fb_location, fb_tagged_' at line 1' in

I affraid the "`from`" and "`with`" names causes this, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [Quoting Reserved Words](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words):

> Sometimes it is necessary to quote a column or table name because of reserved word conflicts. Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically, because it leads to more problems than it would solve. Quoting tables and column names needs to be done explicitly using ticks in the definition.
>
> ```php
> <?php
> /** @Column(name="`number`", type="integer") */
> private $number;
> ```
>
> Doctrine will then quote this column name in all SQL statements according to the used database platform.
>
> > #### Warning
> >
> > Identifier Quoting does not work for join column names or discriminator column names unless you are using a custom `QuoteStrategy`.
>
> For more control over column quoting the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\QuoteStrategy` interface was introduced in 2.3. It is invoked for every column, table, alias and other SQL names. You can implement the QuoteStrategy and set it by calling `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration#setQuoteStrategy()`.
>
> The ANSI Quote Strategy was added, which assumes quoting is not necessary for any SQL name. You can use it with the following code:
>
> ```php
> <?php
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AnsiQuoteStrategy;
>
> $configuration->setQuoteStrategy(new AnsiQuoteStrategy());
> ```

Comment: and how to quote in .yml file?

Comment: @JohnSmith In YAML files, you can add in double-quotes ticks. E.g. " ` column_name ` " <-- remove spaces

Answer (score 1):

For `yaml` orm mapping you have to specify column with escaped quotes :

```
fields:
   order:
     column: "`order`"
     type: integer
```