# Escape symfony column name

Tags: php, database, symfony

im working with Symfony 2.8 and I have to use a database that a coworker gived to me to implement an API, etc.

I have to do the admin backend site and my problem is that the database have a column named 'order' and it's a reserved SQL word, so when I try to save some data it doesent work, but if I change it by 'orderr' it works.

I can't change the column name and i want to make it works with 'order' name.

Is it posible to escape that or something like that in the declaration of the property on his entity?

Thanks and sorry for my English :D

```
EDIT: that doesen't works:
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="'order'", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $order;
```

Comment: try using backtics

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#basic-mapping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Doctrine save fields which are reserved keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725695/can-doctrine-save-fields-which-are-reserved-keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the Entity name:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="`order`")
 */
class Order
{
    //...
}
```

Escape the column name:

```
<?php
/** @Column(name="`order`", type="integer") */
private $order;
```

Remember, use backticks, not single quotes!

Comment: It doesent works for me, keep having the same problem.

Comment: Use backticks `not single quotes '